# Validation.cfc failing on File Upload

Tags: validation, coldfusion

I am using the validator.cfc from Riaforge.org for validation. Here is the link to the CFC:

**http://validation.riaforge.org/**

I am using the following code for validation:

```
<cfset stcDirectories = StructNew()>
  <cfset stcDirectories.Image = Application.userImages>   
  <cfset request.validate.setFields(form)>
  <cfset request.validate.setDirectories(stcDirectories)>
  <cfset request.validate.validate()>
  <cfdump var="#request.validate.validate()#" abort>
  <cfif request.validate.getErrorCount() is 0>
    <cfset result = Application.tools.uploadLogo(form)>
   </cfif>
```

I tried above code and every time it gives me a message:

```
*There was no upload directory specified.*
```

The Reason for this seems valid but if i dump every single variable, i get the dump for the `stcDirectories.Image` Struct

As my `Application.userImages` give me proper path like

```
c:\myproject\admin\userimages
```

Update #1: 
I dumped the Structure to see what values I am getting:

```
C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\myproject\admin\userimages
```

so, it is not identfying it anyways, I am not sure what is the trouble with this

Comment: Start with a clean copy of `upload.cfm`. Run it and make sure it is working "as is" first. Then add in your variables, one at a time. Looks like you omitted a key from `stcDirectories`.

Comment: *..copy of upload.cfm* ie From the project documentation

Comment: Tried the validator.cfc as it is, working fine, may be because it is just uploading the file in the main directory rather than a upload directory. Let me try that..., okay so that did not worked too. My Updates are in the Main Questions

Comment: i solved it, but i used the file field name as `"Image"` and it worked, not sure why it behaved like that...

Comment: Honestly I have not used it and only glanced at the example, but noticed it has two keys in the `stcDirectories` structure. Whereas your code only has one. Perhaps that is responsible for the difference?